# Composer is slow on my windows machine, but fast on a VM (ubuntu) on the same machine

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I have windows on my machine, when I run composer commands; for this we will install a cached version of laravel, it is much much slower than a vm on the same machine with ubuntu (1/6 of the specs of my machine)

**Windows: (I limited it to 25 seconds)**

[image]

**Ubuntu**

[image]

As you can see, the ubuntu version is at least 4/5 times faster, I have even disabled windows defender on my machine, which sped it up, but nowhere near the speed of what it should be, so my question is, what can be causing this, and do you have an recomendations to fix it?

Comment: It is well known that the I/O performance is slower in WSL. Because the inststruction has to go through several layers. There is a thread you can join, here https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/873. Did you see any CPU and RAM high usage during that process? If yes then kill those processes to free up some resource.

Comment: Windows Filesystem is deadly slow. In a VM you are using a Linux filesystem. If you mount the Linux filesystem in the host OS, you will notice Linux's speed gets crippled too. I'm trying to figure out a solution. It's 2019 damn it!